# Basis of 2x2 matrices vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

There is a problem according to which, the vector space of 2x2 matrices is written as the sum of V (the vector space of 2x2 symmetric 2x2 matrices) and W (the vector space of antisymmetric 2x2 matrices).
It is okay I have proven that.

But then we are asked to find a basis of the vector space of 2x2 matrices. The excercise says that this basis MUST consist of both symmetric and antisymmetric matrices.

I have difficulty in that point. I have found that the basis of 2x2 Matrices space is the standard one
{[1 0,0 0],[0 1,0 0],[0 0,1 0],[0 0,0,1]}. Is my way of thinking right?

I would appreciate of your guidance.

Comment: Well, if the question says "write it a basis involving symmetric and anti-symmetric matrices", [0 1,0 0],[0 0,1 0] are right out, as they are neither symmetric nor anti-symmetric.

Comment: In that case, the basis asked is {[1 0,0 0], [0 0,0,1]}?

Comment: You have found "a" basis not "the" basis.  It is not the only one.  Yours does not have the requested properties but another one might.

Comment: Ok really helpful, I see. In that case the basis asked Could be {[1 0,0 0],[0 1,-1 0],,[0 0,0,1]}?

Comment: The space has dimension four, so whatever answer you come up with, if it doesn't have four matrices, it can't be right. What you're meant to do is to find a basis for $V$, and find a basis for $W$, and then the union of those two bases will be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Consider
$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\0&0\end{array}\right]\ ,\
\left[\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\1&0\end{array}\right]\ ,\
\left[\begin{array}{cc}0&0\\0&1\end{array}\right],
$$
as some basics symmetric ones and
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cc}0&-1\\1&0\end{array}\right]
$$
for an antisymmetric.

Answer (score 0):

How about $\{[1,0,0,0],[1,1,1,1],[0,-1,1,0],[0,0,0,1]\}$?

Or, replace $[1,1,1,1]$ with $[0,1,1,0]$.

Note: you can only have one antisymmetric one